# Installing wkhtmltopdf on Python 3.6 Alpine

Tags: python, docker, wkhtmltopdf, alpine-linux

Has anyone been able to install wkhtmltopdf on python:3.6.0-alpine.

I have tried all the solutions present on the internet. I need to use pdfkit which internally uses wkhtmltopython to convert html to pdf.

Comment: It has a alpine package: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86/wkhtmltopdf

Comment: Install it inside your `Dockerfile`

Comment: you mean apk add wkhtmltopdf?

Comment: Yes. Have you tried it ?

Comment: this question may become relevant again, because wkhtmltopdf is not available in the Alpine 3.15 repository (released 2021-11)

Answer (score 8):

You might need wkhtmltopdf and xvfb to run on a server:

```
apk add wkhtmltopdf xvfb
```

Comment: You can also add fonts `apk add fontconfig freetype ttf-dejavu ttf-droid ttf-freefont ttf-liberation ttf-ubuntu-font-family`

Answer (score 1):

In case someone would like to have the full line that needs to be added to the Dockerfile:

```
RUN apk update && apk add wkhtmltopdf
```

or:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wkhtmltopdf
```

You can then use the following code in your "Dockerized" Python script:

```
import pdfkit
path_wkhtmltopdf = '/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkhtmltopdf)
pdfkit.from_string(html, '<direction/of/the/report.pdf>', configuration=config)
```